# Why can't I see how many people favorited my question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, bookmarks

In full site you can see how many people favorited my question.

[image: .]

One person, in this case.

But in the mobile version, there is no number.

[image: .]

Can the number of people who favorited your question be implemented into the iOS app?

Comment: mobile theme and the apps are totally different things, with different teams of devs working on them. Please start separate request for each, if you like.

Comment: Other than narcism, does it matter?

Comment: @ShadowWizard So I can only choose one of the two in this request?

Comment: @ColeJohnson yes, for example badge progress.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 I have already edited but yes, better have one at a time.

Comment: The android app does not have this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no good reason, it was just never done.  Coming in the next build.

[image: Screenshot showing Favorite toolbar item with score.]